# Приложение Android. Авторизация. Оптимальный способ хранения строки на устройстве

Tags: java, android, авторизация

Нужно сохранить локально буквально одну строку вида "ключ: значение". Буду использовать это для авторизации в приложении следующим образом: пользователь вводит логин/пароль, связывается с удалённой БД MySQL, приложение получает id этого пользователя (которое мне и нужно хранить), далее с помощью запросов к удалённой БД с этим id хочу получать все необходимые мне данные для каждой активити (ФИО, связанные с пользователем сообщения и т.д.). Соответственно, если пользователь выйдет из приложения, id нужно удалить из памяти устройства. **Собственно вопросы:**

1. Допустимо ли использовать такой способ для обеспечения авторизации?
2. Какой способ хранения данных в данном случае будет самым удобным (подключать локальную БД или может можно как-то легче сделать для одной строки)?

Comment: 1. Access token;
2. SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В андроиде есть класс SharedPreferences, он позволяет хранить настройки в виде хмл-файла в каталоге приложения. При удалении приложения этот файл также удаляется. Если мобильным приложением пользуется один человек на каждом устройстве, то тогда лучше использовать идентификатор устройства. (Передавать его на сервер при регистрации и связывать с пользователем). Если версия апи выше 28 тогда примерно так(если ниже то можно запросить серийный номер или IMEI):

```
   id = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

ну или хранить его в настройках примерно так.

```
String id= "-";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //добавь ниже дефолтного кода. 
    id = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("id","N/A");
}
//добавь при выходе пользователя 
void onLogout()
{
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    .edit()
    .clear()
    .apply();
}
//добавь при получении идентификатора. 
void onLogin(String newId)
{
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .edit()
            .putString(id, newId)
            .apply();
}
```